# What expression fits the best for the intended meaning?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idioms, expressions

I'm looking for an expression that would mean someone takes control over someone else, like in a bad relationship, when someone takes a dominant posture in spite of the other person. Google would translate this sentence :

> You got your grip on me

As so in french. Though I know "get a grip" has a totally different meaning, so I suspect it isn't correct.

I also encountered this sentence :

> You took hold of me

Please tell me if these google translations have meaning to you and if not, what would be the most appropriate expression to use.

Comment: As you say, metaphoric ***get a grip** [on oneself]* has a totally different meaning (keep or recover one's self-control). That doesn't imply *She's got him in her grip* can't be used metaphorically, but it wouldn't be common. Consider alternative metaphoric references, such as *She's got him **on a string*** (she's a "puppet-master"), or *She's got him **dancing to her tune*** (she's the controlling choreographer). Moving further afield, ***...under her thumb*** (physically constrained, unable to act or move without her permission).

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is very close to an idiomatic phrase:

> To have (got) a [grip | hold] on [somebody | something].
>
> You've got a grip on me.
>
> You have a hold on me.

There is also a Beatles song called ["You Really Got A Hold On Me"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rokS8Ao4nQ)

Note that the first time the title is sung, it's:

> You**'ve** really got a hold on me

Then the backing singers repeat it without ['ve] as in the title.

From Wiktionary:

> #### Noun
>
> [**hold**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hold#Noun) (*plural* **holds**)
>
> 6. Power over someone or something.
>
>    - 2008, Christopher Clarke-Milton, Dawn of the Messiah - Book 1, →ISBN, page 199:
>        The Judge accepts the payment, the law no longer has a **hold** on you, and therefore you are free to walk out of the court a free man or woman.
>    - 2013, Wim Wenders & Mary Zournazi, Inventing Peace: A Dialogue on Perception, →ISBN, page 107:
>        War has a **hold** on our cultural imaginations as an inevitable force, it is peace that has no benefactor.

"grip" is often a synonym of "hold".